# ERROR when i create a project from an existing source

Tags: android

I am trying to create a project from an existing source, but when i hit new android project, then existing source (Choose my source), then choose the api, then when i hit finish it gives me an error saying the project has an invalid description.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "Create project from existing source", you need to create a new directory and then put the project directory tree into that new directory. Then point to the new directory when importing.